# Kivy Python using a button to open a .kv file to change the GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to use a button to cycle through GUI displays on a screen
Here is the code that i've tried for using a main file and then the 2 extra files. The code itself works i keep getting a "Builder is not defined" error which won't load the new file onto screen

The goal is to have a button which will change screens to the next screen and back again

Any help is much appreciated

Main file

```
# import subprocess
# import kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')


class CustomRow(FloatLayout):
    pass


class CustomGrid(FloatLayout):
    pass


class RotationApp(App):
    OilTemp = NumericProperty(0)
    print(OilTemp)

    def build(self):
        print("building...")
        return Builder.load_file('oiltemp.kv')


# the __name__ idiom executes when run from command line but not from import.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    RotationApp().run()
```

Second file

```
<oiltemp>:
    CustomRow:
        FloatLayout:
            id: 0
        FloatLayout:
            id: 1
        # etc, creating as many FloatLayouts as many number of columns you want.

    CustomGrid:
        CustomRow:
            id: 0
        CustomRow:
            id: 1


        Image:
            source: 'OilTempV2.png'
            size: self.texture_size

        Image:
            source: 'NeedleV1.png'
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_x': .5}

        Button:
            text: 'Next Screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            pos_hint: {'left_x': .5, 'bottom_y': .5}
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle: 0
                    origin: self.center
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix
```

Third file

```
<airtemp>:
    CustomRow:
        FloatLayout:
            id: 0
        FloatLayout:
            id: 1
        # etc, creating as many FloatLayouts as many number of columns you want.

    CustomGrid:
        CustomRow:
            id: 0
        CustomRow:
            id: 1


        Image:
            source: 'AirTempV1.png'
            size: self.texture_size

        Image:
            source: 'NeedleV1.png'
            size: self.texture_size
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_x': .5}

        Button:
            text: 'Next Screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            pos_hint: {'left_x': .5, 'bottom_y': .5}
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle: 0
                    origin: self.center
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix
```

Comment: Have a look at [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the help John!